# RestKit The mapping operation was unable to find any nested object representations at the key paths searched

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I want to post a request with `User` object to  register but I am getting this error:

> The mapping operation was unable to find any nested object representations at the key paths searched

Here is my code for posting the request:

```
User * user = [[User alloc]init];
user.UserName = _userNameTextField.text;
user.Password = _passwordTextField.text;
user.ConfirmPassword = _passwordTextField.text;
user.Email = _emailTextField.text;
//    {
//        "Email": "sample string 1",
//        "UserName": "sample string 2",
//        "Password": "sample string 3",
//        "ConfirmPassword": "sample string 4"
//    }
RKObjectManager * objectmanager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"]];
RKObjectMapping * userMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"Email",@"UserName",@"Password",@"ConfirmPassword"]];


RKRequestDescriptor * registrationDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:userMapping objectClass:[User class] rootKeyPath:@"api/Account/Register/" method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
[objectmanager addRequestDescriptor:registrationDescriptor];

[objectmanager postObject:user path:@"api/Account/Register/" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSLog(@"Success");
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Fail");
}];
```

Any help is extremely appreciated.

**Solution**

The  solution was to delete the root key path.

Comment: What's the JSON response sent from the server?

Comment: I am getting 400 Bad request

Comment: You should first fix `400 Bad Request` problem. Did you set your mime-type for your requests by  `[objectmanager.HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:RKMIMETypeJSON];` and `[objectmanager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];`?

Comment: Also you are doing `POST` so you'll probably need to have some kind of authorization token set in the header according to the API's authentication logic. Otherwise, you might get `401 Unauthorized` this time.

Comment: @ozgur I have added your suggestions and I have got no new results , Please see the error, I've edited the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Try remove trailing slash in path (@"api/Account/Register" instead of @"api/Account/Register/")
2. If nothing changed, turn on logging to trace level for object mapping `RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);`  You will see additional information in console.